# Navigation between pages and tabs with .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

**What I want is that when I press this button the tab opens**

In my xaml code i send the following route on button press

**code .xaml**

```
 <Button Text="Tabbes"
            Command="{Binding TabbedCommand}"
            Margin="105,0,0,10"
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            Grid.Row="1"></Button>
```

code that executes **TabbedCommand**  .cs

```
  private INavigationService _navigationService;

  public ICommand TabbedCommand { get; private set; }

                  TabbedCommand = new Command(
                 execute: () =>
                {
             _navigationService.NavigateToAsync("//Tabbeds");
                 });
```

this is the code of my **AppShell.xaml**

```
 <FlyoutItem FlyoutItemIsVisible="False">
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent Route="Tabbeds" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate viewstab:Tabbed}" />
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
```

this is the code of my **AppShell.cs**

```
  public AppShell(
        INavigationService navigationService,
        AppShellViewModel viewModel)
    {
        BindingContext = viewModel;
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override async void OnHandlerChanged()
    {
        base.OnHandlerChanged();

        if (Handler is not null)
        {
            await _navigationService.InitializeAsync();
        }
    }
```

this is the code of my **App.cs**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App(
        INavigationService navigationService,
        AppShellViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new AppShell(navigationService, viewModel);
    }
```

ContentPage works fine when you call it, but it tries to call the following tab bar `Tabbed.xaml`

```
<TabBar  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="GraphMAUI.Views.PTabbed.Tabbed"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:GraphMAUI.Views.PTabbed"
             Title="Tabbed">
            <views:TabInventory/>
</TabBar>
```

**Tabbed.cs**  in this .cs the **ERROR** appears     **HERE**  InitializeComponent();

```
public partial class Tabbed : TabBar
{
    public Tabbed()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and I get the following error

[image]

**System.InvalidCastException
Mensaje = Specified cast is not valid.**

Comment: 1.  May I known which platform does the error occurs?  2.You can refer to [.NET MAUI Shell navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0) 3. If possible,
Could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo link?